# what's the error using supply test set for prediction

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, data-mining, weka

I am trying to analyze the titanic dataset and build a predictive model. I have preprocessed the datasets. Now while I am trying to predict using the test set and I don't know why it doesn't show any result.

[image: Error]

[Titanic_test.arff](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VqlztkhYtwvwZPFU-6CHOpZ2gLoimR-M/view?usp=sharing)
[Titanic_train.afff](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CCES0HqhSpK9TF8-cnL36tjN6rSaNt4K/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the two files (training and test set) you will notice a difference: in the training set the last column has value `0` or `1`, whereas in the test set it has `?` (undefined).

This means that your test set doesn't contain the answers, therefore Weka cannot do any evaluation. It could do predictions though.

Comment: the test set doesn't contain any class value. so, how can I do it?  Can you explain a bit?

Comment: Okay! I have got this. Thanks a lot for your answer.